# Merging TFRecord Datasets

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I have 2 `TFRecordDatasets`. One has an image and corresponding embeddings. The other has the corresponding embeddings and the image features. I want to make a dataset which now has Image, embeddings and the features.

```
d1(image,embeddings),d2(embeddings,features) ----> D(image,embeddings, features)
```

Answer (score 0):

TfRecordDataset can be combined by using `zip` function.
Find the below sample working example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
images = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 4)  
embeddings = tf.data.Dataset.range(4, 7)  
features = tf.data.Dataset.range(7, 9)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((a, b, d))
for element in ds.as_numpy_iterator():
  print(element)
```

Output

```
(1, 4, 7)
(2, 5, 8)
```

Comment: this is when you assume the order of pictures, embeddings and features is the same - how about each has a common key - e.g object_id ? how can one merge based on that key ? thanks